# Phonegap: How to call C algorithm

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I have a PhoneGap app using JavaScript and HTML.
I write a image processing algorithm in C and I try to call the algorithm in Phonegap app(s). But I do not know How to do or what is kind of library should I generate for iOS apps or android apps.

Answer (score 2):

Well, It's easy. The only thing you need to do is writing a PhoneGap pluging.

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins

Here is the HelloWorld demo.

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/guide_plugin-development_index.md.html

after that you can call js function to using that C algorithm.

Comment: probably you cannot call C code from Javascript atleast not for android (no idea about iOS). What needs to be done is to use the Android NDK (Native Development Kit) and JNI. Then use the phone gap plugin to call the Java code which will inturn call the C code.

Comment: I am sorry, I always use iOS.

Comment: To meadlai: I am sorry for the mistake. I deleted it. To Dilberted: I know the way you mentioned in Android. But I want to generate a lib, like .lib or .a which can be used by phonegap. Is it possible?

Comment: @user1632323 of course, you can use Xcode to build a lib, like lib.a, Haha, Object-C is support the standard C. It also can run Cpp programe.